# Field named value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

I'm using 'rails-settings-cached' gem and I want to add ability of creating/updating settings in backend. Model has fields: 'var', 'value', etc... As form builder I'm using Formtastic-bootstrap.
When I doing `f.input :value` I get `no implicit conversion of nil into String`. I think that the reason is that 'value' is a keyword.
How can I solve my problem?
Thank you!

UPD:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @setting], :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
<%= f.semantic_errors :var, :value%>
<%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :var %>
    <%= f.input :value, :as => :text %>
<% end %>
<%= f.actions :class => 'form-group' do %>
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
      <%= f.action :submit %>
      <%= f.action :cancel %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code, where are you using f.input :value?

Comment: try `f.input :value, :input_html => { :value => f.object.value || '' }`, if it works I explain and improve.

Comment: if `f.object` does not work try with `@setting`

Comment: @LearnRailsFastandFree both methods are wrong